# How to make the transition from LaTeX2e to expl3 syntax?

Tags: expl3, latex3

I was peeking at the `LaTeX3` Github repository and specifically `l3auxdata.dtx`. There was a surprise for me, as I have been practicing and studying the `expl3` syntax and modules for the last couple of weeks. The surprise was code like:

```
\def\auxwrite{\auxdata_write:nn}
\def\auxshipout{\auxdata_write_shipout:nn}
```

I am not too sure if there was a reason for the code to use `\def`, but this reminded me of my own difficulties with the syntax.

There is a great temptation when starting with `expl` to bypass the verbosity of the `expl` language and use `\def` and `TeX` primitives. When I started with `expl3` I was literally translating `LaTeX2e` code in my head and then writing it down. Pretty much like when you learn a foreign language.

I have by now mostly overcome this as I forced myself to do the following:

1. Avoided `\def`s.
2. As the too many underscores bothered me, at the beginning I wrote functions as
   `\module_dosomething:nn`. This way I was a bit quicker with debugging and typing. Only started adding `l_` or `g_` much later or on refactoring the code.
3. I mentally kept reading the commands together with the argument specifier until it started sinking in. Like `module dosomething en en`. The reason I kept forgetting to write the specifier.
4. When I used a `tex_<cs>:D` like a command, I went back and refactored the code later to remove it.
5. Write notes with examples as I practice the commands. This can be also useful to others.

Do you have any additional tips and tricks to share?

Comment: Something that I should have done is revise the interface3.pdf semi-quickly, so you get a general idea of what's available. That is, get an idea of what `seq`, `prop`, `clist`, `tl`, `box`, `msg`, `keys`, `fp`, `file`, `bool`, etc. You will get the idea of what's there already done; you will avoid being in a situation when you discover that `prop` or `seq` exists that could have solved 30 minutes of your code that you wrote two days ago. I think getting that general idea is fast (less than half an hour) and then, when you see a problem yo *know* where to see if there's something ready for you.

Comment: @LeonMeier isn't there some TeX-loving-millionaire somewhere who would be thrilled to finance a prof for 10 years to do the work? Or even better, a team of 5 skilled TeX scripters over a timespan of 2 years or something like that? Your comment conveys a sad prospect.

Comment: I think that the only way to.learn how to use it is to use it:)

Comment: Since when are functions meant to start with `\l_` or `\g_`?

Comment: Is your question really: how to go from TeX to expl3? Because your examples aren't using 2e syntax at all ....

Comment: +1 for too many underscores. I am really unable to use that syntax .

Comment: Maybe see also [latex3 - Where I can find introduction to programming in expl3? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558814/where-i-can-find-introduction-to-programming-in-expl3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

> As the too many underscores bothered me, ...

> +1 for too many underscores. I am really unable to use that syntax.

For people who don't like underscores in LaTeX3 programming layer (`expl3`), now there is a new [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package for you. It provides intuitive LaTeX2 interfaces for `expl3`.

It also emulates functional programming in other programming languages such as `Lua`. the evaluation of composite functions is from inside to outside. Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{functional}
% make every function become a group
\Functional{scoping=true}

\begin{document}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \MathSquare { m } {
  \IntSet \lTmpaInt { \IntEval {#1 * #1} }
  \Return { \Value \lTmpaInt }
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\MathSquare{5}
\MathSquare{\MathSquare{5}}

\end{document}
```

Note that with this package, you need to pass return values of functions with `\Return` command.