# Calling a Global Variable using Expl3

Tags: macros, expl3

I've written a macro for my document that producing a random discontinuous but otherwise smooth curve, given a few randomly assigned points. I then ask what the output is for particular (not random) values of the input, this is using `expl3` and `TikZ`. Now I'm trying to take one of the randomly generated outputs using in the macro and reference it in the document but I can't seem to figure out how to do it, and haven't found anything explicit enough for me to understand. This is what I've written:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumitem}
\usepackage[first=-20, last=20]{lcg}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{calculus}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xfp}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-}, every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}

\newcommand{\randi}{\rand\arabic{rand}}

\ExplSyntaxOn\newcommand{\intR}[2]{\chgrand[first=#1, last=#2] \randi}\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\addsub}{\pgfmathrandomitem{\choice}{choices1}\choice}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{choices1}{{+}{-}}

\newcommand{\subnone}{\pgfmathrandomitem{\choice}{choices3}\choice}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{choices3}{{}{-}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_LeftEnd_int
\int_new:N \l_LeftMid_int
\int_new:N \g_hole_int
\int_new:N \l_RightEnd_int
\NewDocumentCommand{\smoothplot}{}
{
\int_set:Nn \l_LeftEnd_int { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 5 } }
\int_set:Nn \l_LeftMid_int { \int_rand:nn { -2 } { 2 } }
\int_set:Nn \l_RightEnd_int { \int_rand:nn { -4 } { 5 } }
\int_gset:N \g_hole_int { \l_LeftMid_int }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=1\textwidth,
        height=0.5\textwidth,
        grid=major,
        xmax=4.5,
        xmin=-4.5,
        ymin=-4.5,
        ymax=5.5,
        xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4},
        ytick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
        ylabel={$g(x)$},
        xlabel={$x$}
          ]
\addplot [smooth, red, mark=none, thick] coordinates
    {(-4, \l_LeftEnd_int) (-3,2*rand-2) (-2,2*floor{rand}) (-1,3*rand+1) (0,3*floor{rand}) (1, \l_LeftMid_int+2) (2,\l_LeftMid_int)};
    
\addplot [red, only~marks] coordinates {(-4, \l_LeftEnd_int) (2, \l_LeftMid_int) (4, \l_RightEnd_int)};

\addplot [red, mark=o] coordinates {(2, \l_LeftMid_int+2)};

\addplot [smooth, red, mark=none, thick] coordinates {(2, \l_LeftMid_int+2) (2.7, rand+3) (3.3, 2*rand+1.5) (4, \l_RightEnd_int)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hole}{} % This is the part that I'm trying to get to reference the variable
{
\g_hole_int
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section*{Problem 3}

\smoothplot \\
Find the values for $x  = -4, -2, 0, 2, 4$.\\
Find the domain and range of $g(x)$.\\
% \ADD{\hole}{2}{\temp}\sol % This line doesn't work, but I'll revisit this
% \hole
For what value(s) of $x$ does $g(x) =$ \hole + 2
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Sorry for the blurriness

Comment: please use the expl3 naming convention. Your variables should have a module name part.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you describe this naming convention more, or could you give an example / correction to what you mean? Also, are you saying this will fix this issue or just giving advice about better practice?

Comment: see expl3.pdf (open it with `texdoc expl3`) for the naming scheme, and no it will not solve your problem, that is only about best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd separate the `expl3` from the Ti*k*Z/pgfplots part.

In the `expl3` part the plot building command is passed three random integers already in explicit form.

The `\makesmoothplot` command also globally defines `\hole` to expand to the desired value.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.18,
  every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
  every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-},
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\smoothplot}{}
 {
  \exp_args:Neee
  \makesmoothplot{ \int_rand:nn {  1 } { 5 } }% LeftEnd
                 { \int_rand:nn { -2 } { 2 } }% LeftMid
                 { \int_rand:nn { -4 } { 5 } }% RightEnd
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\definehole}{m}
 {
  \tl_gset:Nx \hole { \int_eval:n { #1 + 2 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\makesmoothplot}{mmm}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=1\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    grid=major,
    xmax=4.5,
    xmin=-4.5,
    ymin=-4.5,
    ymax=5.5,
    xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4},
    ytick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
    ylabel={$g(x)$},
    xlabel={$x$}
  ]
  \addplot [smooth, red, mark=none, thick] coordinates {
    (-4, #1)
    (-3,2*rand-2)
    (-2,2*floor{rand})
    (-1,3*rand+1)
    (0,3*floor{rand})
    (1, #2+2)
    (2,#2)
  };
  \addplot [red, only marks] coordinates {
    (-4, #1)
    (2, #2)
    (4, #3)
  };
  \addplot [red, mark=o] coordinates {(2, #2+2)};
  \addplot [smooth, red, mark=none, thick] coordinates {
    (2, #2+2)
    (2.7, rand+3)
    (3.3, 2*rand+1.5)
    (4, #3)
  };
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \definehole{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Problem 3}

\smoothplot

Find the values for $x  = -4, -2, 0, 2, 4$.

Find the domain and range of $g(x)$.

For what value(s) of $x$ does $g(x) = \hole$?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I added `\int_use:N` infrom of my global variable for the `NewDocumentCommand{\hole}`, also I changed the variable names:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_point_LeftEnd_int
\int_new:N \l_point_LeftMid_int
\int_new:N \g_point_LeftMid_int
\int_new:N \l_point_RightEnd_int
\NewDocumentCommand{\smoothplot}{}
{
\int_set:Nn \l_point_LeftEnd_int { \int_rand:nn { 1 } { 5 } }
\int_set:Nn \l_point_LeftMid_int { \int_rand:nn { -2 } { 2 } }
\int_set:Nn \l_point_RightEnd_int { \int_rand:nn { -4 } { 5 } }
\int_gset:Nn \g_point_LeftMid_int { \l_point_LeftMid_int }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        width=1\textwidth,
        height=0.5\textwidth,
        grid=major,
        xmax=4.5,
        xmin=-4.5,
        ymin=-4.5,
        ymax=5.5,
        xtick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4},
        ytick={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
        ylabel={$g(x)$},
        xlabel={$x$}
          ]
\addplot [smooth, red, mark=none, thick] coordinates
    {(-4, \l_point_LeftEnd_int) (-3,2*rand-2) (-2,2*floor{rand}) (-1,3*rand+1) (0,3*floor{rand}) (1, \l_point_LeftMid_int+2) (2,\l_point_LeftMid_int)};
    
\addplot [red, only~marks] coordinates {(-4, \l_point_LeftEnd_int) (2, \l_point_LeftMid_int) (4, \l_point_RightEnd_int)};

\addplot [red, mark=o] coordinates {(2, \l_point_LeftMid_int+2)};

\addplot [smooth, red, mark=none, thick] coordinates {(2, \l_point_LeftMid_int+2) (2.7, rand+3) (3.3, 2*rand+1.5) (4, \l_point_RightEnd_int)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hole}{}
{
\ADD{ \int_use:N \g_point_LeftMid_int }{ 2 }\sol~
\sol
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Could someone comment on why I needed to include `\int_use:N` for the `\hole` command but not for when calling the variables in my `\smoothplot` command?

Comment: What’s the reason for using `\ADD` and not the built-ins of expl3?

Comment: Outside of me not having any familiarity with the `expl3` functions, not much. I was using it later in the document so I know how it works. I wish I new `expl3` a lot better, but unfortunately I cannot find any good tutorials going over how to code with it. The only resource I have is a rather dense 16 page document that hasn't helped me much

Comment: Old comment, but [latex3 - Where I can find introduction to programming in expl3? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558814/where-i-can-find-introduction-to-programming-in-expl3?noredirect=1&lq=1) has a link to Alan Shawn's blog (basic programming guide only. No token manipulation/input stream manipulation etc., unfortunately.). The API reference is in interface3.pdf which is... yes, dense.