# How to remove any kind of spaces at the beginning of something

Tags: macros, spacing

This is another chapter of the story "how to use a moodle database for my purposes".
The accepted answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644183/how-to-check-that-something-starts-with/644222?noredirect=1#comment1605453_644222) gives a very effective way to retrieve informations from an exercise database structured as follows

```
\begin{multi}{}
  Text
  \item first answer
  \item* correct anser
  ...
 \end{multi}
```

Now, the object retrieved as "nth answer" contains all kind of spacing, for instance

```
  \item

  first answer
```

will store the `\par`.

I would like to erase all kind of "blank" spaces before the start of the actual aswer, for editing purpose.

---

An example for the Wipet answer which does not fit in a comment. If I set

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{getitems}
  \begin{document}

  \def\item{\futurelet\next \itemA}
  \def\itemA{\ifx\next\par \expandafter\itemB \fi}
  \long\def\itemB#1{\item}

  \def\A{


  A}

  \def\B{%


  B}

  X\expandafter\item\A X

  X\expandafter\item\B X
 \end{document}
```

The output is

```
 X
 AX
 XBX
```

So `\expandafter\item\A` does not work (it includes a linebreak before `A`) while `\expandafter\item\B` works (it does not include a linebreak before `B`)

Comment: \tl_head, \tl_tail and \tl_if_eq etc. should be sufficient

Comment: @user202729 what is the usage of such?

Comment: by the way: I need also to remove empty lines AFTER my object

Comment: @user202729 I tried something like `\NewDocumentCommand{\HEAD}{ m }{\tl_head:N { #1 }}` and ` \NewDocumentCommand{\TAIL}{ m }{\tl_tail:N { #1 }}` and then `\HEAD\A\TAIL\A`, with `\A` as in the question, and does not work (whil it works with `\B`)

Comment: Sorry, it is not full example. In what context is used `\def\A{...}\def\B{...}`, i.e. what is around them? How the `\item` is defined? Full example means that it can be used without adding another context which I don't know. Full example is full document.

Comment: @wipet my real life full example is the second code of the accepted answer to this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644183/how-to-check-that-something-starts-with-or-how-to-build-your-own-exercise-she/644222#644222 where its is constructed a macro which handle a moodle database extracting all items of an exercise: text, answers, correct answers, and store them in some macro. Then I use those defined macros for building my exercise sheets. But those macros contains everything it is between two `\item`, included blank lines, and this fact bugs my final rendering,

Comment: @wipet see also this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644469/problem-with-spaces-and-getitems-package/644472#644472 in which I tryed to isolate the issue in a simple code

Comment: Your examples mentioned in your last comments don't include `\def\A` nor `\def\B`. So, I still don't know, how looks like your full example with `\def\A` and `\def\B` and `\expandafter\item\A` and `\expandafter\item\B`. You are talking that it does not work and I am unable to construct a full example which documents your claim. I am waiting for full example or we close this discussion.

Comment: @wipet added a full code of "non working" example

Comment: You have `\def\A{ ` but should be `\def\A{%`. The `\item` macro skips only `\par` tokens, no spaces. My firs idea were that `\item` is followed by the real text, so there is no spaces immediately after `\item`. But the space were propagated from expanded macro `\A` in your example.

Comment: Why aren't you using the code I suggested? It just requires to have an up-to-date release of the TeX system.

Comment: @greg The first reason is very silly: I have some problem with the repositories of ubuntu which I need to solve,  and it takes some times. I'm usign overleaf for tests in this period but it seems that also overleaf is not completely up to date. The second reason is that I work with existing moodle databases, and, if I have understud correclty, your code does not accept itemize inside questions and aswers (but I cannot test it untill I get my upgrade).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\item` control sequence consumes all space after it at during tokenization. So, you want to remove only blank lines tokenized as `\par`. If you don't asking for expandable macro, the solution can look like this:

```
\def\item{\futurelet\next \itemA}
\def\itemA{\ifx\next\par \expandafter\itemB \fi}
\long\def\itemB#1{\item}

test:

aaa%
\item 


bbb

\bye
```

**Another approach:** Suppose we have defined something like this:

```
\def\TEXT{
\item 


a b c
\item
d e f

g h i
}
```

and we want to create a new macro `\TEXT` where all `\par` immediately followed by `\item` are removed. It means that the two `\par`s after first `\item` are removed in our example but the `\par` between `d e f` and `g h i` is kept. We can do this by

```
\rempars\TEXT
```

This macro changes the body of the `\TEXT` as mentioned above. This macro can be defined by:

```
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\long\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}
\def\rempars #1{%
   \let\orig=#1%
   \def\tmp{}%
   \expandafter\remparsA #1\item\par\endrempars
   \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\tmp}%
   \ifx#1\orig\else \afterfi{\rempars#1}\fi
}
\long\def\remparsA #1\item\par#2\endrempars{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax \addto\tmp{#1}%
   \else \addto\tmp{#1\item}\afterfi{\remparsA #2\endrempars}\fi
}
```

Comment: maybe I was not so clear. Everything is part of macros that I use for producing some Exams shet from moodle database, as in here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644183/how-to-check-that-something-starts-with-or-how-to-build-your-own-exercise-she/644222#644222 . So `getitems` already parses `\item` occurrences, than therefore disappear. All text between `\items` is stored in a macro `\gathereditem{n}` and I would like to extract the information as `\def\mymacro{content of \gathereditem with spaces removed}`

Comment: Before the text is gathered (it is separated by what?) then you can set the TeX register `\endlinechar` to -1. It suppresses the conversion of blank lines to `\par`. I don't know the whole context, so I cannot say more.

Comment: before the text is gathered it is in the form `\begin{multi}{} text of exercise \item first answer \item another answer \item* correct answer ... \end{multi}` and `getitems.sty` package parses it.

Comment: could you explain what exactly does your code? it seems looping

Comment: also I tried to turn your code in a macro but it does not work. basically because `\def\TEST{\par \par \par test}` and then `\item\TEST` don'e see the \par (because the braces are there?)

Comment: `\expandafter\item\TEST`

Comment: That's strange. `\expandafer` works if I have `\def\TEST{\par \par test}` but doesn't if, instead of `\par` I have blank lines (like as in the example of the original question)

Comment: It needs full example what you are doing. Such example cannot be included in the comment.

Comment: added example in the question

Comment: @user126154 I added another approach which can solve your problem. I suppose that you have accumulated the text in a macro `\TEXT` and you want to do corrections in it.

Comment: the new macro does not fit with my need. My accumulated text is not stored as in your example, it is stored by themacro `\gatheritems`. I guess that in my case `\TEXT` is something like `\par \par some text that may contains nested enviromnent like itemize \par \par \par` and I want to remove all initial and final `\par`. Se here for an example of situation that I need to handle https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644469/problem-with-spaces-and-getitems-package/644472#644472

Answer (score 1):

Add something to the code I suggested last time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{exercise}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{multi}{m +b}
 {
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \stepcounter{exercise}
  \textbf{Exercise~\theexercise}~--~#1\par\nobreak
  \moodle_multi:n { #2 }
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
 }
 {}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showcorrect}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_true:N \g_moodle_multi_correct_bool
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\hidecorrect}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_falsee:N \g_moodle_multi_correct_bool
 }

\bool_new:N \g_moodle_multi_correct_bool
\seq_new:N \l__moodle_multi_text_seq
\tl_new:N \l__moodle_multi_text_tl
\tl_new:N \l__moodle_multi_moretext_tl
\tl_new:N \l__moodle_multi_answers_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \moodle_multi:n
 {
  \regex_split:nnN { \{(enumerate|itemize)\} } { #1 } \l__moodle_multi_text_seq
  \tl_set:Nx \l__moodle_multi_answers_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__moodle_multi_text_seq { -1 } }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__moodle_multi_text_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { (.*)\u{l__moodle_multi_answers_tl} } { \1 } \l__moodle_multi_text_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__moodle_multi_text_seq { \item } \l__moodle_multi_answers_tl
  % the first item will contain the question text
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__moodle_multi_text_seq \l__moodle_multi_moretext_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__moodle_multi_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__moodle_multi_moretext_tl
  % now we rebuild the answers
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),nosep,labelsep=0.75em]
  \use:e
   {% add the first \item and put it also between the other items
    \__moodle_multi_item: \seq_use:Nn \l__moodle_multi_text_seq { \__moodle_multi_item: }
   }
  \end{enumerate}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__moodle_multi_item:
 {
  \item 
  \peek_charcode_remove:NT *
   {% there is an asterisk
    \bool_if:NT \g_moodle_multi_correct_bool { \__moodle_multi_correct: }
    \__moodle_multi_ignore:
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__moodle_multi_correct:
 {
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^{\scriptscriptstyle*}$}\hspace{\labelsep}}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__moodle_multi_ignore:
 {% remove blank spaces and \par
  \peek_regex_remove_once:nTF { [\s\c{par}]* } {} {}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{multi}{Name of the question}
  Text of the question
  \begin{itemize}
  \item a
  \item b
  \end{itemize}
  More text
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item a
  \item b
  \end{enumerate}
  More text
  \item first answer
  \item 

second answer
  \item* the starred is the correct answer
\end{multi}

\showcorrect

\begin{multi}{Name of the question}
  Text of the question
  \item first answer
  \item second answer
  \item*

the starred is the correct answer
\end{multi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: my LaTeX is not up to date: I have no` \peek_regex_remove_once`

Comment: @user126154 Update.

Comment: by the way: your code is much cleaner than all other solutions I found/build without expl3. It's clear that expl3 is the right solution for "programming" with latex.

Comment: @greg I don't know exacly how your code works, but it seems that it searches for all instances of \item, and this is probably the problem with itemize environment inside questions/answers. This seems the same way listofitems package do (and in fact it has the same problem). On the other hand getitems has not this problem. I don't know if one could take inspiration from that and use the same receipt with expl3. Probably yes, but I don't know.

Comment: @user126154 Not with the latest version.

Comment: so the latest version of your code accepts itemize?

Comment: @user126154 I'm referring to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644322/4427 where you can see both `enumerate` and `itemize` in the “text” part. Anyway, trying to coerce bad markup is a waste of time. It takes less to edit the texts to use something else than `\item` in the “answers” part.

Comment: I see. Well the fact is that first, I need to use existing moodle database (which are written with `\item`) and second, the script should be available to all my collegues, so it has to be something that "works out of the box" with any moodle database that they have.

Comment: You are right, searching for "bad markup" is a waste of time. However, it seems to me that  `\getitmes` does not do that: it just seems to recognize the beginning of enviroments inside text and aswer and take them without parsing inside them. May be one could do in a similar way with come expl3 command

Comment: In the doc package of `getitems` there is the whole code commented, and this issues is explicitly discussed. It seems that it takes few lines to solve it, but my knowledge is not enough to pick what I need from that code.

Comment: @user126154 I provided you fully functioning code fulfilling the requests, which *does* work out of the box on any up-to-date TeX system. If you don't want to use it, that's your choice.

Comment: Oh, I will test and use it. That's sure :)  My concerns is: ok we checked for occurrences of `itemize` and `enumerate` but it may happens that answers contain some other nested environment invoking some `\item` command, and in this case the code would probably stop working. So, a solution in style of `getitems` would be more appropiate.