# problem with spaces and getitems package

Tags: macros, spacing

When gathering items, I would like to avoid inital and final blank lines and spaces.
I explain with an example.

Here my code

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{getitems}
  \NewEnviron{test}{
    \expandafter\gatheritems\expandafter{\BODY}
    }{}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{test}
  Text
  \item one%
  \item
  
  two  

 \end{test}

 X\gathereditem{1}\ignorespaces X

 X\gathereditem{2}\ignorespaces X

\end{document}
```

The output is

```
XoneX
X
two
X
```

Well, I would like to get rid of all spaces, `\par` and anything else, and make the output of `X\gathereditem{2}\ignorespaces X` to be `XtwoX`. In other words, I would like to ignore all blank lines and spaces heading ant trailing the actual content of the item.

NOTE: I'm interested in a general use, so in general, `\gathereditem{2}` may contain complicated text like mathematical formulas and nested environments (as enumerate, itemize) which I don't want to mess. Just remove intial and final blank lines and space.

NOTE: I have the same problem with `listofitems` package

Comment: the requirement seems a bit strange, normally each item is a paragraph so the normal way to normalise 1 and 2 would be to add `\par` at start and end, so 1 looked like 2.  If you want to ignore `\par` do you want to ignore all of them or just the first and last?  if the item had three paragraphs, would you want them run together, or kept as paragraphs except for the last one, which loses a `\par` ?

Comment: I want to ignore all intial `\par` as well of all final. and item could be of the form `\item some initial \par <some text that may contains nested environments > some final \par` and I want to retain just `<some text that may contains nested environments >` discarding initial and final par, spaces etc. As the ambient `itemize` would do.

Comment: as I say that is _not_ what the "ambient itemize" would do, rather it does the opposite: it _adds_ `\par` at the start and end of the document supplied text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think that my reference to itemize was misleading. I removed from the text of my question. (At least: it is clear what I'm asking for?)

Answer (score 1):

The `listofitems` package can be made to absorb `\par`s.  However, it will then not be able to differentiate a multi-paragraph item, from two successive items, as shown in the last case.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{listofitems,environ}
\setsepchar{\item||\par}
\ignoreemptyitems
  \NewEnviron{test}{
    \greadlist*\mylist{\BODY}
    }{}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{test}
  Text
  \item one%
  \item
  
  two  

  \item

   First par

   Second par

 \end{test}

 X\mylist[1]X

 X\mylist[2]X

 X\mylist[3]X

 X\mylist[4]X

 X\mylist[5]X

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative would be the introduction of a newcommand `\mylistminuspars[<list number>]` to strip out the pars through the use of nested lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{listofitems,environ}
\setsepchar{\item/\par}
\ignoreemptyitems
  \NewEnviron{test}{
    \greadlist*\mylist{\BODY}
    }{}
\def\mylistminuspars[#1]{%
  \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[#1]{%
    \z%
  }%
}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{test}
  Text
  \item one%
  \item
  
  two  

  \item

   First par

   Second par

 \end{test}

 X\mylistminuspars[1]X

 X\mylistminuspars[2]X

 X\mylistminuspars[3]X

 X\mylistminuspars[4]X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, if one wanted to retain pars, except for leading and trailing pars, a small modification to the above will obtain it:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{listofitems,environ}
\setsepchar{\item/\par}
\ignoreemptyitems
  \NewEnviron{test}{
    \greadlist*\mylist{\BODY}
    }{}
\def\mylistminuspars[#1]{%
  \foreachitem\z\in\mylist[#1]{%
    \z%
    \ifnum\zcnt<\listlen\mylist[#1]\par\fi
  }%
}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{test}
  Text
  \item one%
  \item
  
  two  

  \item

   First par

   Second par

 \end{test}

 X\mylistminuspars[1]X

 X\mylistminuspars[2]X

 X\mylistminuspars[3]X

 X\mylistminuspars[4]X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there something similar to `\ignoreemptyitems` for `getitems` package?

Comment: @user126154 You'd have to look at the documentation or talk to the developer.

Comment: if one uses `listofitems`, then one has problems with nested itemize environment, that is to say in case an item of `test` contains an itemize environment. That's why I skipped to `getitems`. I tried also to use your code applied to any single macro `\gathereditem{n}` but still the nested environment problem is present. It seems that parsing all occurrences of `\par` is not the right strategy.