# L3 programming layer interface for latex3

Tags: expl3

The L3 programming layer interface for latex was introduced to provide better syntax and library for LaTeX programmers.  With little material about the language, where can I find its technical manual?

Comment: `texdoc interface3` or `texdoc expl3` for a higher level overview. Also look at https://www.alanshawn.com/latex3-tutorial/  No idea why you say "little material" ?

Comment: I find that the way the documentation is presented is quite complex.  Would there be any chance to have a brief description with instructions on how one can navigate the extensive documentation and get to the information one wants.  It is particularly difficult for beginners.

Comment: Does the language permit use of `hyphen (-)` in addition to `underscore (_)` for variables?

Comment: You asked for a "technical manual" interface3 is a full listing of every function defined, there is also `l3kernel` which is documented source code. Neither is intended as a tutorial, see  instead the  https://www.alanshawn.com/latex3-tutorial/ I showed above (which is not by the latex team)

Comment: no, you could try that or see any intro, you do not need a technical manual for that kind of question,

Comment: Yes, I asked for technical manual.  But also interjected about a short summary for making sense of `https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/`.

Comment: You are right of course, but I would need the manual to understand code of others.

Comment: Unfortunately not really. [latex3 - Where I can find introduction to programming in expl3? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558814/where-i-can-find-introduction-to-programming-in-expl3?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @user202729 As David's already mentioned, there's a good overview available online from a non-team member