# Documentation for programmers regarding expl3

Tags: expl3, documentation

Does there exist documentation for programmers regarding `Latex3` ?  With details about `\cs`, `\tl`, `\use`, and so on ?

Comment: you did get these answers last year https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660279/l3-programming-layer-interface-for-latex3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with all texlive packages, you have documentation installed on your system.

`texdoc expl3`  will give a top level view

`texdoc interface3` is a reference manual of every defined function in the L3 kernel.

In general the LaTeX project website has links to documentation and announcements of new features

https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/#general-documentation

Comment: You cannot expect one to have an installed setup to see some document on latex.  Besides, one has to know beforehand what one wants (expl3).  There needs to be an easy way to see what is available as basic (user documentation, programmer documentation e.g. Latex3 Layer).

Comment: that's why the documentation is on ctan, or use https://www.learnlatex.org/en/ or use the official manuals, the latex book and latex companion. @Veak sepending on what level you need.

Comment: @Veak and of course I can expect that you have tex (and its documentation) installed.  L3 programming layer is programming layer to extend latex, it is not expected that someone without access to a latex system would start by modifying its source code before even using the system.

Comment: Look, I might be on a remote system or doing fieldwork and I just grab some system.  From what you are saying, I cannot do any work this way.  The real world works much different than what you are implying.

Comment: @Veak you can use ctan or texdoc.net to look up documentation online.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. See the relevant PDF documents listed here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel.

Comment: Could they not be included in the Latex Team Website ?

Comment: @Veak Documentation for installed (La)TeX packages is available using `texdoc` for your TeX system. This includes `expl3`, and means that the documentation you read will match the code you have available. Putting rather arbitrary versions on websites is not a great idea.

Comment: the website has links at https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/#general-documentation

Comment: I would say - Remove Publications from the main page and introduce "Documentation" and "Support",  Put all latest standards (use and development) in the main page of "Documentation" without people having to navigate through many links.  Then have any other less important documentation, notes etc with links.  The way to get a useful document on `latex-project.org` is the worst I have ever seen.